# Python getting 'sqlite3.OperationalError: table percipitation already exists' my code so far

Tags: python, sqlite

```
def create_precipitation(db, data_file):
    """(str, reader) -> NoneType
    Populate the database db with the contents of data_file.
    Create a table called Precipitation, with four columns: City
    (text), Snow (real), Total (integer), Days (integer).

    Parameters:

    db: name/path to a database

    data_file: contains one city, snowfall amount, total
    precipitation amount, and number of days per line, separated by
    comma.
    """  
    conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('create table precipitation' +
                '(city text, snow real, ' +
                'Total integer, Days integer)')
    for line in data_file:
        values = line.strip().split(',')
        city = values[0]
        snow = float(values [1])
        total = int(values[2])
        days = int(values[3])
        cur.exectue("insert into percipitation values (?,?,?,?)",
                    (city, snow, total, days))
    conn.commit()
    cur.close
    conn.close()
```

"dont understand how the table already exists"
"code error is just confusing"
"when i run the code it looks like this 'create_precipitation("weather.db", open("precipitation.txt"))'

Comment: Welcome on SO! You might first want to check out the formatting of your question and fix it, by hitting the ``edit`` button right below your question text. While you are at it, you might want to add a bit of text which explains the issue you are having :) [and what you have tried to solve it]

Comment: Well, you do not want to create the table each time you're doing an `INSERT`. So you can specify to only create the table if it's not already there using: `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ...`

Comment: ^I think this would work ive seen it around ill give it a shot thanks

Answer (score 0):

def create_precipitation(db, data_file):

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('drop table if exists precipitation')
cur.execute('create table precipitation' +
            '(city text, snow real, ' +
            'Total integer, Days integer)')
for line in data_file:
    values = line.strip().split(',')
    city = values[0]
    snow = float(values[1])
    total = int(values[2])
    days = int(values[3])
cur.execute("insert into precipitation values (?,?,?,?)",
            (city, snow, total, days))
conn.commit()
cur.close
conn.close()
```

I've done this so far and its getting closer to working I still am not done yet tho and don't know what to do next